# How to use Stripe's secret key and publishable key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, https, stripe-payments

I would like to connect with the Stripe API using a https call using the https library.

```
var https = require('https');
```

I have gotten the secret key and publishable key and put it inside a object:

```
var stripe = {
  secret_key: 'secret_key_given_in_the_dashboard',
  publishable_key: 'publishable_key_given_in_the_dashboard'
}
```

I am now in the part of creating the requestDetail object:

```
var requestDetails = {
    'protocol'  : 'https:',
    'hostname'  : 'api.stripe.com',
    'method'    : 'POST', //WHICH OF POST GET PUT DELETE SHOULD I USE?
    'path'      : '???????????????????????',// WHICH ENDPOINT SHOULD I USE?
    'auth'      : '???????????????????????',// SHOULD I USE THE SECRET AND PUBLISHABLE KEY HERE?
    'headers'   : {
      'Content-Type'  : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length' : Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload)
    }
  };
```

I plan to make use of the requestDetails object in the call using https:

```
var req = https.request(requestDetails, function(res){
      // Grab the status of the sent request
      var status = res.statusCode;
      //Callback successfully if the request went through
      if(status == 200 || status == 201) {
        callback(false);
      } else {
        callback('Status code returned was ' + status);
      }
    });
```

Where and how should I use the secret key and publishable key in order to make a call to the stripe API?
Which endpoint?
Which method (POST, GET, PUT,or DELETE)?

I would like to eventually create a order and pay through the STRIPE api.
But for now just any authenticated call through the stripe api will do as I need a sample format that works....
I'm not too sure where to add the secret key and publishable key....

Comment: Secret key will use at server side and publishable key will use by client side to call any stripe API, like to generate token for payment etc.

Comment: How to use? any examples using https?

Answer (score 2):

You should install official `stripe` package (source: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node), require the package and authenticate it using your secret key ( example from the github docs):

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('your_stripe_secret_key');

stripe.customers.create({
  email: 'customer@example.com',
})
.then(customer => console.log(customer.id))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

The package is an abstraction to make the API requests for you.

More docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=node

However, if you want to use the `https` directly for Stripe API requests, which is not recommended, you can check the docs and examples for using the cURL, since it shows the endpoints for each example.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication?lang=curl

Comment: Hi I'm doing this as an assignment and I think i'm not allowed to use a library...I have to use https.... the curl examples doesn't show where to put the keys in the header and what key?

Comment: @preston you need to use stripe library,

Answer (score 0):

try using fetch, `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sk`.

My working example of retrieving a customer based on the `customer_id`:

```
const url = `https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/${stripe_customer_id}`;
return await fetch(url, {
  method: "get",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sk,
  }
})
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    // console.log(response);
    return response;
  });
};
```